# Template Parameters in Graph Class Based on STL's map Class

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, vector, graph-theory

I am writing a header file for a simple graph class implemented using the STL's map class. However, I am having issues with the template parameters, it seems to be telling me that I can't declare vector and map objects "without a type" but I can't see how I'm not giving it the type it needs. Also, the vector and map classes are included with directives. `private:` is commented out for testing. I feel like it's a syntax error of some kind.

Graph.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

template <typename T>
class Graph
{
public:
    Graph();
    Graph(const Graph<T>& other);
    Graph& operator=(const Graph<T>& other);
    ~Graph();

    vector<T> AdjacentNodes(const T& n);

//private:
    map<T, vector<T>> m;
};
```

Comment: Did you prepend `map` and `vector` with `std::` in your real code?

Answer (score 1):

To use the map and vector class, you will need add below header files

```
#include <map> 
#include <vector>
```

and also map and vector are part of the std namespace. there fore you need to use std::map , std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

(following block taken from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/ , which I suggest you check out!)

```
template < class Key,                                     // map::key_type
           class T,                                       // map::mapped_type
           class Compare = less<Key>,                     // map::key_compare
           class Alloc = allocator<pair<const Key,T> >    // map::allocator_type
           >
```

First of all, make sure you put "using namespace std;" at the top or prepend std items such as map vector with `std::`

Secondly, as shown in the template above, if your `typename T` is not a data type for which `std::less` is defined you need to create your own comparison function (can be a function pointer or function object) and enter it as the third template argument.

Finally, be careful about putting `>>` in `map<T, vector<T>> m;` if you are using older compilers you will need to include a space between the last two `>`'s

Comment: also, if you want the vector to be private you can just put it before you write `public:` at the top of your class declaration because classes default to private for its members.

Comment: Half tempted for -1 for the suggestion of "put `using namespace std`" into a header file.  It's true that it would fix the issue but it's bad advice.

Comment: thanks for the heads up and I appreciate the comment instead. Good to know for the future!